# .IMG file conversion to a QGIS readable format

Tags: qgis, garmin

I recently found QGIS and enjoy being able to play with it, most importantly it can convert almost anything to .mbtiles, a format that is readable by foreflight on iOS.

Now I have an OLD .IMG file that we use in our GPS to follow a certain powerline. My knowledge of gps data is limited and that file is the only copy I have of that

I would like to read that file in QGIS, but I can't find anything online, only that... well I can't

I have been able to open the file in GPSMapEdit, I can see the line, I can see the poles and everything.

I have been able to convert parts of it to a .kml and then upload it to QGIS but a lot of information from the original file is not there

I've thought about saving it to a .mp file from MapEdit but still.. no luck..

TL:DR I want to convert a Garmin IMG to a readable format for QGIS

Comment: FYI I have found this : http://gwprojects.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2470 , but I cannot get it to work since my version of QGIS is 3+

Comment: garmin basecamp open img file and export to gpx? qgis will read the .gpx file.

Comment: Thanks but no the .img is a map file cannot be opened conventionally on BaseCamp.